# $A=\{E \in \Sigma : \forall\epsilon>0\,\exists C\subset E\subset U,\,C\text{ closed , $U$ open, and }\mu(U-C)<\epsilon\}$

Tags: measure-theory

$(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a measure space, $X$ is metric space and $\mu(X) = 1$.

I need to prove that the collection
$$
A=\{E \in \Sigma : \forall\epsilon>0\,\exists C\subset E\subset U,\,C\text{ closed , $U$ open, and }\mu(U-C)<\epsilon\}
$$
is a $\sigma-$ algebra.

To show $\emptyset \in A$ and that $A$ is closed under complements i did.

How can I prove $A$ is closed under countable unions?

Thanks for helping .

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\mu(U-C)<\epsilon$ in the definition?

Comment: And shouldn't $\mathcal A$ be the collection of sets $E$ of $\Sigma$ such that for any positive $\varepsilon$, there exists a closed set $C$ and an opent set $U$ such that $C\subset E\subset U$ and $\mu\left(U\setminus C\right)\lt\varepsilon$?

Comment: At least your definition of $A$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra. Davide's $\mathcal A$ is.

Comment: Then it is not a sigma algebra. Not even an algebra. Just think of two sets $E_1$ and $E_2$ which are sufficiently far away from each other.

Comment: What do you think? Your attempt with $C_n$ and $U_n$ works.

Comment: @amsmath Can you elaborate? (Note that $C$ and $U$ don't need to be connected sets.)

Comment: To show that $\bigcup E_i$ is in the set, I think you want $C_i\subset E_i\subset U_i$ such that $\mu(U_i-C_i)<\epsilon/2^i$. EDIT: Oh, $\bigcup C_i$ need not be closed...

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Connectedness is not an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can prove that $A$ is closed under taking complements and finite unions by yourself, right? Now, let $E_n\in A$, $n\in\mathbb N$, and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Put $E := \bigcup_n E_n$. First, construct pairwise disjoint $E_n'\in A$ such that $E = \bigcup_n E_n'$ by taking complements and finite unions of the $E_n$'s. Then $\sum_n\mu(E_n') = \mu(E)\le\mu(X) = 1$. Hence, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\sum_{n\ge N}\mu(E_n') < \varepsilon/4$. Now, choose $C'$ and $U'$ such that $C'\subset\bigcup_{n<N}E_n\subset U'$ and $\mu(U'-C') < \varepsilon/2$. Also choose $U_n\supset E_n'$ such that $\mu(U_n-E_n') < 2^{-n-2}\varepsilon$ for $n\ge N$. Now, put $C := C'$ and $U := U'\cup\bigcup_{n\ge N}U_n$. Then $C\subset E\subset U$, $C$ is closed, $U$ is open, and
\begin{align*}
\mu(U-C)
&= \mu\left((U'-C')\cup\bigcup_{n\ge N}U_n\setminus C'\right) < \frac\varepsilon 2 + \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\ge N}U_n\setminus C'\right)\\
&\le \frac\varepsilon 2 + \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\ge N}U_n\right)\\
&= \frac\varepsilon 2 + \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\ge N}U_n-\bigcup_{m\ge N}E_m'\right) + \mu\left(\bigcup_{m\ge N}E_m'\right)\\
&\le \frac\varepsilon 2 + \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\ge N}(U_n-E_n')\right) + \frac\varepsilon 4\\
&\le \frac{3\varepsilon}{4} + \sum_{n\ge N}\mu(U_n-E_n')\,\le\,\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
So, the "trick" is not to choose the union of all $C_n$'s (which might be non-closed) but only a finite union which is already sufficiently "close" to $E$.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you upvoted my answer. I have spent some time on thinking about your question - including chatting with you in the chat room.